# NET6 API exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a simple WebAPI Project with NET6.

The Controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MenuController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly UnitOfWork uow;

    public class MenuRequestDTO
    {
        public Guid? StoreOid { get; set; }
    }

    public MenuController(UnitOfWork _uow)
    {
        uow = _uow;
    }

    [HttpPost(Name = "full-download")]
    public async Task<WebMenu> MenuFullDownload(MenuRequestDTO data)
    {
        return await MenuDataHandler.GetFullMenu(uow, data.StoreOid!.Value);
    }
}
```

I always get this exception when trying to call the URL `http://localhost:5253/Menu`.

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: EntityTypes must be not null and contains minimum 1 item
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataLayerFactory.<>c.<PrepareDataLayerFactoryFunc>b__3_3(Context ctx)
   at lambda_method2(Closure, Context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataLayerFactory.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareDataLayerFactoryFunc>b__21()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.XpoServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<AddXpoCustomSession>b__2(Guid key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.XpoServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass14_1`1.<AddXpoCustomSession>b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method11(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The message of exception isn't found via google in any use case.

Does anybody have a hint of what could be wrong?

Comment: Your Entity supply null instead of value. 1 more thing you don't have any get method in controller as per your URL mention in Description. Share your full code with service as well

Comment: Your entity type should be non-nullable, but you passed null. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what happens if you try to hit /menu/full-download   ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is your `MenuFullDownload` action is a `HttpPost`, and the request does not have the body.

##### Use Thunder Client or Post man

Maybe you can use [Thunder Client](https://www.thunderclient.com/) or [Post man](https://www.postman.com/) to send request with a body to hit the `endpoint`.

Comment: This is incorrect. He doesn't set the `Route` to `full-download`, he's setting the `Name`. Totally different. Did you read the question? It's clear the endpoint is being hit -- the request is coming from Swagger.

Comment: Sorry,  I had updated my answer. Hope this can help